# Use ng-controller and $routeProvider at the same time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

The issue is that I have an index page, whith a(some) partial(s) view(s) that we can call "A.html" with a controller "ACtrl" assigned by $routeProvider, but inside that partial view, I would like to use a different controller for some divs using ng-controller to include a "A1Ctrl".

Is this possible?

Not focus on any code, but in the concept if this is barely possible and how?

I tried to include in the partial view something like this with no success:

A.html

```
... //Other stuff for this partial view
<div ng-controller="A1Ctrl">
   {{message}}
</div>
```

... //More stuff for this partial view

I have included the .js where the A1Ctrl is defined to the index page with same result. Any tip?

**UPDATE:**

I have create in plnkr a sample code to show what I want to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/hdpLMK3DbzNdz2KeHPEB?p=preview

I have partial view generated after clicking "Say hi" which has its own template ("first.html") and controller, injected by the $routeProvider. But in that partial view in first.html I want to add a  which has its own controller for only that section of code. But I can't make it work, any suggestion?

I also tried to use Dependency Injection to include the module "multilinguage" into router.js with no success because it seems to generate an error.

*index.html*

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  ... //Other imports
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="router.js"></script>
  <script src="multilanguage.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  <a href="first">Say hi</a> |
  <a href="second">Say bye</a>
  <br/>

  <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>

</html>
```

*first.html*

```
{{message}}
<div ng-controller="MultiLang">
  {{message}}
</div>
```

*router.js*

```
var app = angular.module('router', ['ngRoute', 'multilanguage']).
config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.
    when("/first", {
        templateUrl: "first.html",
        controller: "EngLang"
    }).
    when("/second", {
        template: "Bye man!"
    });
});

app.controller('EngLang', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hi guys';
});
```

multilanguage.js

```
angular.module('multilanguage', []).
controller('MultiLang', function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hallo, Hola, Ciao, Ni Hao"
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you including partial views?

Comment: Check my update, I include them with a $routeProvider.

Comment: Sorted out! See Update & Update 2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, also you can use nested controllers, for example:

```
<div ng-controller="A1Ctrl">
    {{ message }}

    <div ng-controller="subCtrl">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, review my update with a plnkr code and an explanation.